# Linking opencv to Visual studio windows form application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to link opencv to Windows Form application VS 2010. I m using the tutorial

http://linkopencvtovs.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-link-opencv-to-microsoft-visual.html.

It is working fine for console application but it wont allow me to use any function of opencv in GUI based program.. gives errors below..

Error 1 error C2065: 'IplImage' : undeclared identifier c:\users\ayesha\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\abc\abc\Form1.h 130 1 abc 
Error 2 error C3861: 'cvLoadImage': identifier not found c:\users\ayesha\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\abc\abc\Form1.h 130 1 abc

code is simple GUI

## pragma once

namespace abc {

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;


/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

    protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  path;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  summary;
protected: 


    private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->path = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->summary = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(392, 68);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"browse";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // path
        // 
        this->path->Location = System::Drawing::Point(23, 68);
        this->path->Name = L"path";
        this->path->Size = System::Drawing::Size(304, 20);
        this->path->TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // summary
        // 
        this->summary->Location = System::Drawing::Point(153, 156);
        this->summary->Name = L"summary";
        this->summary->Size = System::Drawing::Size(159, 27);
        this->summary->TabIndex = 2;
        this->summary->Text = L"summaize video";
        this->summary->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->summary->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::summary_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(556, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->summary);
        this->Controls->Add(this->path);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
```

## pragma endregion

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Stream^ myStream;
    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.avi)|*.avi|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
    {
        if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
        {
            path->Text = Convert::ToString(openFileDialog1->FileName);

            // Insert code to read the stream here.
            String ^ temp = "you have successfully browsed a video";
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(temp);

            myStream->Close();
        }
    }
}
```

private: System::Void summary_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("dss");
         }
};
}

Comment: Include required opencv h-file to Form1.h

Comment: Including opencv h-file gives many errors

Comment: Error 5 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> > const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@@Z) C:\Users\Ayesha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\abc\abc\abc.obj abc

Comment: I hava added all headers file in project.cpp file above  main()

Comment: Now add opencv libraries to linker.